# confusion about Cache-Control HTTP header

Tags: javascript, html, http, caching

I have two questions regarding HTTP cache using the `Cache-Control` header:

1. How does the browser identify which request can be fulfilled using the existing cache? Is the browser checking if the endpoint matches? But even requests to the same endpoint can have different `body` or config, I don't quite understand how does the browser know when to use the cache and when to not use the cache given the time it sends out the request is still within the time frame specified by `max-age` in the response's `cache-control` header?
2. I recently learned that both request and response can set `max-age` in their own `cache-control` header. I understand that the request's `max-age` would tell the server (or any intermediate caches) how fresh of response the client is willing to accept from them. The response `max-age` (or lack thereof) tells the client how long it can consider that response to be fresh. (feel free to correct me if I am wrong). But what would happen in this scenario:
   let's say the response has a `max-age` for one year and then we send another request for the same resources with `max-age` being `0`. Does that make the browser ignore the cache? or Does the browser accept the cache and not send out the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information from [this specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching). According to the document,

1. The cache entry contains the headers of the request:

> As discussed above, caching servers will by default match future
> requests only to requests with exactly the same headers and header
> values.

This means that you get one entry in your cache every time you make exactly the same request to the server (the cache can be personal or shared, like in a proxy). In practice, for entities that only cache GET requests, the key can be the URI of the request. By the process of  `normalization`, two very similar requests can share a cache entry. The decision to use the cached entry depends on several factors, as detailed below. The figures in the document explain this very well. Bottom line, `max-age` only determines *freshness*, not the behavior of the cache.

2. According to this specification, the cache is never ignored if the entry exists. Even a *fresh* entry can be discarded to save disk space, and a *stale* entry can be kept long after it has expired. The diference is that a *stale* entry is not directly retrieved. In that case, the caching entity (browser/proxy/load_balancer...) sends a *freshness* request to the server. The server then decides whether the cached page is *fresh*.

In summary, if a cached page is *fresh* according to `max-age` and whatever other modifiers are used, the caching entity decides that the cached resource will be used. If it is stale, the server decided whether the cached resource can be used.

EDIT after comment:
To understand the difference between `max-age` sent by the client and the server, we need to dig into [the http protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1). In section 5.2.1., It says

> 5.2.1.  Request Cache-Control Directives
>
> 5.2.1.1.  max-age
>
> Argument syntax:
>
> ```
>   delta-seconds (see Section 1.2.1)
> ```
>
> The "max-age" request directive indicates that the client is
> unwilling to accept a response whose age is greater than the
> specified number of seconds.  Unless the max-stale request directive
> is also present, the client is not willing to accept a stale
> response.

The language seems to indicate that the server is not forced by the directive, but it is expected to honor it. In your example, this would means that the client directive prevails, as it is more restrictive. The client is saying "I do not want any page cached for more than 0 seconds", and the cache server is suposed to contact the server to fulfill the condition.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am still not sure for my second question, what happens if the `max-age` set in the request header and one set in the response header are different...

Comment: I have added more information in the answer, it is true that one needs to dig more into the documents.